# Need help in writing code to search phrase in a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am developing a js file that will take the search string from the Clipboard and will highlight the phrase in the Web page if that is found.
Here I will copy paste the text from ms word.  And I am using below regular expressions to clean word formatting from clipboard text..

```
   var pure = impure.replace(/“/g, "\"");
   pure = pure.replace(/”/g, "\"");
   pure = pure.replace(/’/g, "\'");
   pure = pure.replace(/‘/g, "\'");
   pure = pure.replace(/–/g, "\-");
```

and then searching the phrase with the following method

```
   var body = $('body');
   var replaced = body.html().replace(''+pure+'','<span class="highlight">'+pure+'</span>');
   $("body").html(replaced);
```

With this I am able to find individual words and some small sentences.. But i am unable to find the total phrase at a time...  For example look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F7txy/2/)   fiddle(This works in only IE, cause i am currently targeting IE).

Please suggest me a good way to proceed further.. 
Here my Word may contains Bullets, Newlines, Bolds, Italics etc...

Comment: What do you mean by **total word**? Could you give examples which works and doesn't.

Comment: Please have a look the fiddle given.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't work `'shortcut' is undefined `

Comment: It's missing shortcut.js which is a custom script. I've cleaned it up a bit making it more simplified for OP here: http://jsfiddle.net/F7txy/1/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure *what* was the exact bug you were having doubts about, but I found some bugs of my own in your script.  I fixed them here: http://jsfiddle.net/F7txy/6/

One of the problems is that you appeared to be trying to replace the `pure` text with `pure` again:

```
var replaced = body.text().replace(
    '' + pure + '',
    '<div class="highlight">' + pure + '</div>'
);
```

It looks like you should have been replacing the `impure` with pure:

```
var replaced = body.text().replace(
    '' + impure + '',
    '<div class="highlight">' + pure + '</div>'
);
```

Also, you can chain the `replace` methods together (which I did for you). Also, you *could* combine all of them into one but I'll let you do that.